# Ctrl+w event captured in firefox not working in other browsers

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have code below by which I get the Ctrl+w event of browser but it's only working in Firefox not in other browsers. I found that there is problem with keydown/keypress. Is there any way to write a code to browser compatibility for both event(keydown/keypress).

here is my code:

```
$(window).keydown(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.which == 119 && event.ctrlKey) {
        alert("Ctrl-W pressed");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for only keys that are not set default

Also **you can not overide browser default behaviour using JS**

**Here is quick solution**

**Solution 1(Quick)**

**CODE**

```
$(document).keypress("w",function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey)
    alert("Ctrl+C was pressed!!");
});
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/J4t5d/1/

**Solution 2**

you can do this easily with js library which is 
[shortcut.js](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/55765722/delivred/abdennour/lib/js/shortcut.js)

**Solution 3**

You can do trick like this :)

```
$(window).keydown(function(event) {event.preventDefault();
    if (event.which == 87 && ctrlMode == true) {
        alert("Ctrl-W pressed");
    }    
     return false;
});
$(document).keydown(function(e){e.preventDefault();
 if(e.ctrlKey){
        ctrlMode = true;
 }
});
$(document).keyup(function(e){e.preventDefault();
 if(e.ctrlKey){
     ctrlMode = false;
 }
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J4t5d/5/

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: It's not working. I want this code should work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Use keypress instead of keydown: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J4t5d/2/)

```
$(window).keypress(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (event.which == 119 && event.ctrlKey) {
            alert("Ctrl-W pressed");
        }    

    return false;
});
```

Comment: It's not working in chrome and IE. I want this code should work in all browsers.

Comment: In chrome not possible, You can't override browser behaviour with js  :)